# Can the weep hole of a water pump face upwards?

Tags: cooling-system, water-pump

I've noticed a hole on the top of my water pump, and it looks like the pump's weep hole, since it also has some dried up coolant residue inside (but it isn't leaking any coolant, since the area around it is completely clean).

That hole is facing upwards, not downwards as it logically should (since it's meant to let anything that got past the internal seal drain away by means of gravity; if facing upwards, the coolant needs to overflow first and then it can drip away).

Yes, on my car's engine this location allows one to check for pump seal integrity better, even with the engine on (all you have to do is shine a light between the rocker cover and the water pump pulley), but is the weep hole supposed to be located at the top of the pump, even though it's still on the bearing's housing?

Comment: There is usually one on top and bottom, it does not really matter where it is, it is only a tattle tale to let you know the shaft seal is leaking coolant and the pump should be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

engineers put it there so it' eaiser to see. Dosn't matter about being on top or bottom,see coolant from that hole, shaft seal leaking,pull the pump.Being able to see the weep hole clearly,helps you elimanate the coolant might be leaking from another source.